# python2 second loop inside function * pycharm

Tags: function, loops, csv

why this one works:

```
lis = [8, 5, 6]
   def fun():
       for i in lis:
          print i
       for i in lis:
          print i
fun()
```

and this one not when it is working with csv files:

```
def miladifromhijri(intinp1):#, inp2, intinp3):
    fulyear = intinp1 - 1
for row in majmouaread:
        introw = int(row[0])
        if introw <= fulyear:
            years = []
            years.append(introw)
            near = years[::-1][0]
            nearlessyear = near
for row in majmouaread:#this one doesn't get executed
    print row
```

I want to work with nearlessyear variable next using a second loop, because if i continued on in the first loop the variable doesn't get a constant, it keeps get looped with data that isn't helpful in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are looking for the break statement. Just exit the loop if you found the value you are looking for:

```
def miladifromhijri(intinp1):#, inp2, intinp3):
    fulyear = intinp1 - 1
nearlessyear = 0
for row in majmouaread:
        introw = int(row[0])
        if introw <= fulyear:
            years = []
            years.append(introw)
            near = years[::-1][0]
            nearlessyear = near
            break
for row in majmouaread:#this one doesn't get executed
    print row
```

Comment: Not actually, break would really break me, because It's not clear when to break, so it breaks the loop in the first iteration. I want the loop to end so that near variable gets the first item of the list and get set to nearlessyear variable, and I move forward to the next loop for doing something with. I can make use of it in the same loop, but because of the changing variable near it's not gonna work well, as I can't set a second same loop without break.

Comment: I fear i don't really understand what you are trying to do with the code. If you want to access nearlessyear outside of the loops, just define it outside (Answer updated). The first loop will set the variable and break then. 
You should try to understand the scope of the variables: Your assignment to years in the inner loop will throw away every intermediate result in each cycle of the loop.

Comment: Two things; the break statement is going to stop the nearle... to get the intended result becuase it breaks after one loop. if I define it outside, I have to set another function, if I made it before the miladi... func, then I have to append. How about something that for the first loop to finished and proceed to set the same loop.